# Make CSS height transition smoother

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have the following HTML markup and CSS to build navigation menus:

```css
.submenu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in;
}
.submenu.opened{
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation navigation-main navigation-accordion">
  <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Products</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>All Products</li>
      <li>Popular Products</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I toggle the class `opened` on `submenu` using JavaScript. The `submenu` slides up and down on click with the help of the transition. But I want the transitions as smooth as possible.

How can I improve the above CSS code to make it as smooth as possible, as it doesn't work well if the Product link is clicked in quick succession.

Comment: And where is the javascript

Comment: document.getElementById('.submenu').classList.toggle('opened');

Comment: @ManishJangir Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I guess everybody has another definition of *smooth*, but I would start here with changing the ease function from `ease-in` to `ease-in-out` and than just play with the duration of the transition. **0.3s** is a bit fast in this situation, increase the duration until it fits for you. Here is an example with a duration of 1.5s:

```js
document.querySelector('#prod').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.submenu').classList.toggle('opened');
}, false);
```

```css
.submenu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: max-height 1.5s ease-in-out;
}

.submenu.opened{
  max-height: 200px;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.7
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation navigation-main navigation-accordion">
  <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="prod">Products</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>All Products</li>
      <li>Popular Products</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```